# How to avoid the `calling method getOrCreateDataPartitionTable` error without restarting the ConfigNode in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am currently using 1 ConfigNode and 1 DataNode configuration in the stand-alone mode of Apache IoTDB, and the version is 1.2.1. The code reports an error: `org.apache.iotdb.rpc.StatementExecutionException: 301: [EXECUTE_STATEMENT_ERROR(301)] Exception occurred: insertTablets failed. An error occurred when executing getOrCreateDataPartition():Error in calling method getOrCreateDataPartitionTable, because: Fail to connect to any config node. Please check status of ConfigNodes or logs of connected DataNode`. However, the status of ConfigNode is still running when I check it. I restarted the ConfigNode and then the connection returned normal. I want to know aside from restarting, how can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to upgrade your Apache IoTDB version to 1.2.2. This seems to be a solved bug in this version and see it the new version will avoid your problem.